# How can I use my script to drop constraints in a SQL Server 2012 database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to execute the following SQL:

```
declare @newLine as varchar(1) = char(13);
declare @sqlCmd as varchar(max) = '';
SELECT @sqlCmd = @sqlCmd + 'alter table ' + OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) + ' drop constraint ' + OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) + ';' + @newLine
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc LIKE '%CONSTRAINT'
order by case when left(OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID),2) = 'PK' then 1 else 0 end
exec (@sqlCmd)
```

However this is giving me the following error message:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
```

Can someone give me some advice as to why the message is coming up. This script as far as I know worked before but not now.

Here's what the output looks like when I don't have the select going into a string:

```
alter table Answer drop constraint FK_dbo.Answer_dbo.Question_QuestionId;
alter table Question drop constraint FK_dbo.Question_dbo.Problem_ProblemId;
alter table Question drop constraint FK_dbo.Question_dbo.QuestionStatus_QuestionStatusId;
alter table Problem drop constraint FK_dbo.Problem_dbo.Reference_ReferenceId;
```

Here's the code used to create:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Answer]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Answer_dbo.Question_QuestionId] FOREIGN KEY([QuestionId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Question] ([QuestionId])
```

Comment: Why do you want to drop all constraints ?

Comment: I think there are a lot of reasons why people might want to drop all constraints.

Comment: Yes, it is a valid requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the constaint name in `[]`:

```
declare @newLine as varchar(1) = char(13);
declare @sqlCmd as varchar(max) = '';
SELECT @sqlCmd = @sqlCmd + 'alter table ' + OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) + ' drop constraint [' + OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) + '];' + @newLine
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc LIKE '%CONSTRAINT'
order by case when left(OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID),2) = 'PK' then 1 else 0 end
exec (@sqlCmd)
```